How to upgrade runtime without sudo?
Is it the process below that I just want to confirm?
const preimageHash = await api.rpc.democracy.notePreimage(runtimeWasm);
const proposalHash = await api.tx.democracy.propose(preimageHash, 'New runtime upgrade').signAndSend(alice);

const unsub = await api.query.democracy.referendumInfoOf(proposalHash, (info) => {
  if (info.isNone) return;
  const remainingBlocksUntilEnd = info.unwrap().remainingBlocks.toNumber();
  console.log(`Remaining blocks: ${remainingBlocksUntilEnd}`);
  if (remainingBlocksUntilEnd === 0) {
    const approved = info.unwrap().approved;
    console.log(`Approved: ${approved}`);
    unsub();
  }

